# Pagination WordPress on the home page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, wordpress-theming

I'm having an issue trying to get pagination to work on the homepage of a site I'm working on.

Here is the code I'm using, simplified of course:

How to do pagination for this?

```
<?php $args = array('cat' => '3, 7, 10, 12', 'posts_per_page'=> 3); ?>
    <?php query_posts($args); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();    ?>

            <article class="col-md-12">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >
                    <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url( 'medium' ); ?>"></div></a>
                    <div class="entry entry-table">
                        <div class="title">
                          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><h3 class="h5"><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
                          <span class="cateogry<?php echo get_the_category( $id )[0]->cat_ID; ?>"><?php echo get_the_category( $id )[0]->name; ?></span>
                       <p><?php echo get_excerpt(228, 'content'); ?>
                        <a class="linkmore" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Czytaj dalej ...</a>
                       </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </article>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $args = array('cat' => '3, 7, 10, 12', 'posts_per_page'=> 3); ?>
    <?php query_posts($args); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();    ?>

            <article class="col-md-12">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >
                    <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url( 'medium' ); ?>"></div></a>
                    <div class="entry entry-table">
                        <div class="title">
                          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><h3 class="h5"><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
                          <span class="cateogry<?php echo get_the_category( $id )[0]->cat_ID; ?>"><?php echo get_the_category( $id )[0]->name; ?></span>
                       <p><?php echo get_excerpt(228, 'content'); ?>
                        <a class="linkmore" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Czytaj dalej ...</a>
                       </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </article>

        <?php endwhile; ?> 
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>
  <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;') ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Only the last 3 posts are displayed, even on page 2

Comment: @TomaszB. try adding `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` on the end of the code. Maybe is query cached

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must setup properly your query:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array('cat' => '3, 7, 10, 12', 'posts_per_page'=> 3, 'paged' => $paged);
```

And second, you need to add pagination links out of the loop

```
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>
  <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;') ?></div>
</div>
```

Whole code can looks like this:

```
<?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args = array('cat' => '3, 7, 10, 12', 'posts_per_page'=> 3, 'paged' => $paged);
?>
    <?php query_posts($args); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();    ?>

            <article class="col-md-12">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >
                    <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url( 'medium' ); ?>"></div></a>
                    <div class="entry entry-table">
                        <div class="title">
                          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><h3 class="h5"><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
                          <span class="cateogry<?php echo get_the_category( $id )[0]->cat_ID; ?>"><?php echo get_the_category( $id )[0]->name; ?></span>
                       <p><?php echo get_excerpt(228, 'content'); ?>
                        <a class="linkmore" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Czytaj dalej ...</a>
                       </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </article>

        <?php endwhile; ?> 
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>
  <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;') ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Only the last 3 posts are displayed, even on page 2

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved:

```
<?php
global $paged, $wp_query, $wp;
$args1 = array('cat' => '3, 7, 10, 12');

$args = wp_parse_args($wp->matched_query);
if ( !empty ( $args['paged'] ) && 0 == $paged ) {
$wp_query->set('paged', $args['paged']);
$paged = $args['paged'];
}
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('paged='.$paged.'&showposts=3&cat=3,7,10,12');
?>
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
<article class="col-md-12">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >
                    <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url( 'medium' ); ?>"></div></a>
                    <div class="entry entry-table">
                        <div class="title">
                          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><h3 class="h5"><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
                          <span class="cateogry<?php echo get_the_category( $id )[0]->cat_ID; ?>"><?php echo get_the_category( $id )[0]->name; ?></span>
                       <p><?php echo get_excerpt(228, 'content'); ?>
                        <a class="linkmore" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Czytaj dalej ...</a>
                       </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </article>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
 <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>
```